# Why am I losing the File Object while running this code?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filesystems

Here is my code.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim trgtMchnFldr As Object
Dim fldr As Object
Dim sbFldr As Object
Dim BOMFl As Object
Dim chngOvrFl As Object
Dim mchnSpecFl As Object
Dim flFound As Object
Dim queue As Collection

Dim flToFindName() As Variant
Dim flName As Variant
ReDim mchnSubFldrArr(0) As Variant
ReDim BOMFlArr(0) As Variant
ReDim chngFlArr(0) As Variant
ReDim mchnSpecFlArr(0) As Variant


arrysToSet = Array(mchnSubFldrArr, BOMFlArr, chngFlArr, mchnSpecFlArr)
For Each itm In arrysToSet
    Set itm(0) = Nothing
Next itm

Set trgtMchnFldr = mchnFldr(Range("A1"))
If trgtMchnFldr Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "This machine does not exist."
    Exit Sub
End If

billofMtr = Array("Bill of Material", "BOM")
chngOvr = Array("Changeover", "Change Over")
mchnSpec = Array("Machine Spec", "Spec_Sheet", "Specs", "Spec Sheet")
flNmOrganize = Array(billofMtr, chngOvr, mchnSpec)

Set queue = New Collection

queue.Add trgtMchnFldr

Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set fldr = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1
    Debug.Print fldr.Files.Count
    If fldr.Files.Count > 0 Then
        For Each fl In fldr.Files
            Set flFound = fl
            For flType = 0 To UBound(flNmOrganize)
                For flNm = 0 To UBound(flNmOrganize(flType))
                    If InStr(1, flFound.Name, flNmOrganize(flType)(flNm)) > 0 Then
                        If flType = 0 Then
                            If BOMFlArr(0) = Empty Then
                                ReDim Preserve BOMFlArr(0)
                                Set BOMFlArr(0) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            Else
                                ReDim Preserve BOMFlArr(UBound(BOMFlArr) + 1)
                                Set BOMFlArr(UBound(BOMFlArr)) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            End If
                        ElseIf flType = 1 And Not flFound Like "*.pdf" Then
                             If chngFlArr(0) = Empty Then
                                ReDim Preserve chngFlArr(0)
                                Set chngFlArr(0) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            Else
                                ReDim Preserve chngFlArr(UBound(chngFlArr) + 1)
                                Set chngFlArr(UBound(chngFlArr)) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            End If
                        ElseIf flType = 2 Then
                             If mchnSpecFlArr(0) = Empty Then
                                ReDim Preserve mchnSpecFlArr(0)
                                Set mchnSpecFlArr(0) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            Else
                                ReDim Preserve mchnSpecFlArr(UBound(mchnSpecFlArr) + 1)
                                Set mchnSpecFlArr(UBound(mchnSpecFlArr)) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next flNm
            Next flType
nextFl:
        Next fl
    End If
    For Each sbFldr In fldr.SubFolders
        If sbFldr.Name <> "P1-Inquiry_Proposal" Then
            queue.Add sbFldr
        End If
    Next sbFldr
Loop


errMsg = "Cannot find the file."
Set BOMFl = flNewFile(BOMFlArr())
If BOMFl Is Nothing Then
    Range("E12") = errMsg
Else
    Range("E12").Value = BOMFl.Path
End If

Set chngOvrFl = flNewFile(chngFlArr())
If chngOvrFl Is Nothing Then
    Range("E7") = errMsg
Else
   Range("E7") = chngOvrFl.Path
End If
Set mchnSpecFl = flNewFile(mchnSpecFlArr())
If mchnSpecFl Is Nothing Then
    Range("E13") = errMsg
Else
    Range("E13") = mchnSpecFl.Path
End If
End Sub
```

I seem to lose the file in this section (shown below). I have tried grabbing the file as soon as possible, but when I step through my code I will get an error in the Locals Window `<Application-defined or object-defined error>`. The program recognizes there is a file there. If I go to the Immediate Window and apply a property to the object ie. `?fl.Name`, the Immediate Window will return the value of that property. As soon as I retrieve a value from the File Object, the file will reappear in the Locals Window.

```
            Set flFound = fl
            For flType = 0 To UBound(flNmOrganize)
                For flNm = 0 To UBound(flNmOrganize(flType))
                    If InStr(1, flFound.Name, flNmOrganize(flType)(flNm)) > 0 Then
                        If flType = 0 Then
                            If BOMFlArr(0) = Empty Then
                                ReDim Preserve BOMFlArr(0)
                                Set BOMFlArr(0) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            Else
                                ReDim Preserve BOMFlArr(UBound(BOMFlArr) + 1)
                                Set BOMFlArr(UBound(BOMFlArr)) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            End If
                        ElseIf flType = 1 And Not flFound Like "*.pdf" Then
                             If chngFlArr(0) = Empty Then
                                ReDim Preserve chngFlArr(0)
                                Set chngFlArr(0) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            Else
                                ReDim Preserve chngFlArr(UBound(chngFlArr) + 1)
                                Set chngFlArr(UBound(chngFlArr)) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            End If
                        ElseIf flType = 2 Then
                             If mchnSpecFlArr(0) = Empty Then
                                ReDim Preserve mchnSpecFlArr(0)
                                Set mchnSpecFlArr(0) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            Else
                                ReDim Preserve mchnSpecFlArr(UBound(mchnSpecFlArr) + 1)
                                Set mchnSpecFlArr(UBound(mchnSpecFlArr)) = flFound
                                GoTo nextFl:
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next flNm
            Next flType
nextFl:
        Next fl
```

I copied the whole folder I was trying to retrieve file from and it retrieved the folders without any issues. Since I am convinced this is server side stuff are there any way to bypass this issue?

Comment: Could you describe what the code is supposed to do? I am recognizing at the start of `Do Loop` that it is a way to loop through a folder and all of its subfolders without recursion. There seem to be too many arrays, too much 'Redim-Preserving' and too many `If` statements which make the code quite unreadable.

Comment: This bit of code grabs a folder off of my company's network and it drills down into each subfolder looking for different types of files that I need for customer service. After I find these files I use another function to parse through each array and it gives me the most recent file of that type. I use the ```flNmOrganize``` array to store the the different types of strings that I will use to find the files I need. I know there a lot of ```ReDim Preserves``` , but these are all used to do the same thing just with different arrays.

Comment: I copied the entire folder I was trying to work with, and my code worked first try no debugging needed. It must be something with the server in the network.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty difficult to follow the logic in your code, mainly due to lots of arrays (some nested).  You might find it easier to debug if you re-organize a little and maybe use Collections to store the found files.

Based on my understanding of your posted code (may be a little off...) this should be close:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim fl As Object, fldr As Object, sbFldr As Object
    Dim colBOM As New Collection, colChange As New Collection
    Dim colSpec As New Collection, trgtMchnFldr As Object
    Dim queue As New Collection, fso As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
    Set trgtMchnFldr = fso.getfolder("C:\Temp\")
    queue.Add trgtMchnFldr
    
    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set fldr = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1
        
        For Each fl In fldr.Files
            If NameMatch(fl.Name, Array("Bill of Material", "BOM")) Then
                colBOM.Add fl
            ElseIf NameMatch(fl.Name, Array("Changeover", "Change Over")) Then
                If Not fl.Name Like "*.pdf" Then colChange.Add fl
            ElseIf NameMatch(fl.Name, Array("Machine Spec", "Spec_Sheet", "Specs", "Spec Sheet")) Then
                colSpec.Add fl
            End If
        Next fl
        
        'sub folders for processing
        For Each sbFldr In fldr.SubFolders
            If sbFldr.Name <> "P1-Inquiry_Proposal" Then
                queue.Add sbFldr
            End If
        Next sbFldr
    Loop
    
    'do something with colBOM, colChange, colSpec
End Sub

'does the string `nm` contain any of the strings in `arr`?
Function NameMatch(nm, arr) As Boolean
    Dim e
    For Each e In arr
        If InStr(1, nm, e, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            NameMatch = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next e
End Function
```